# Edit Plist on Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, webserver, plist

I am creating a demo for my employer where you are able to access, and edit data (on a .plist) that is on a server. Currently, I am using Google Sites as my temperary "server" and that is where my plist is.

I am able to read the plist file using this code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://sites.google.com/site/.../myplist.plist";
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSLog(@"Info: %@", [dic objectForKey:@"myKey"]);
```

So my question is, how can I EDIT the data of the plist on the "server"? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

RMK-Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but far more work than it needs to be. You'd need to use the [Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/) to log into the administrative account for your site and upload a new version of the plist file.

You may want to investigate using something like iCloud or [Parse](https://parse.com/) for data storage instead of Google Sites.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I will look into those solutions. iCloud sounds like a possibility, do you know where I might be able to take a look to get some code for accessing iCloud?